# Can we explicitly specify what feature to be extracted from an image while using CNN

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Last day I learned about the convolution neural network, And went through some implementations of CNN using Tensorflow, All the implementation only specify the size, number of filters and strides for the filter. But when I learned about the filter it says that filter on each layer extracts different feature like edges, corners etc.

My question is can we explicitly specify filter which all feature we should extract, Or which portion for the image is more important etc

All the explanation says that we take a small part of an input image a slide across it with convolving. If so do we take all the parts of image and convolve across the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can we explicitly specify filter which all feature we should extract, Or which portion for the image is more important etc

Sure, this could be done. But the advantage of CNNs is that they learn the best features themselves (or at least very good ones; better ones than we can come up with in most cases).

One famous example is the ImageNet dataset:

[image]

In 2012 the first end-to-end learned CNN was used. End-to-end means that the network gets the raw data on one end as input and the optimization objective on the other end.

Before CNNs, the computer vision community used manually designed features for many years. After AlexNet in 2012, nobody did so (for "typical" computer vision - there are special applications where it is still worth a shot).

> All the explanation says that we take a small part of an input image a slide across it with convolving. If so do we take all the parts of image and convolve across the image?

It is always the complete image which is convolved with a small filter. The convolution operation is local, meaning you can compute much of it in parallel as the result of the convolution in the upper left corner is not
dependent of the convolution in the lower left corner.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be confusing filters and channels. A filter is the weight window size in your convolution which can be used to produce channels from the convolution output. It is typically these channels that represent different features:
[image]

In this car identification example you can see some of the earlier channels picking up things like the hood, doors, and other borders of the car. It is hard to truly specify which features the network is extracting. If you already have knowledge of features that are important to the network you can feed them in as an additional mask layer or using some type of weighting matrix on them.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response